# What is the purpose of this thread

Tags: java, multithreading

What is the purpose of thisThread created after all the gui components are initialised? The first few lines are typical boiler plate code when a new GUI is started, but I'm struggling to understand why this thread is started. Found this in an open source project, and I'm wondering why someone would do this.

```
public static void main( String args[] ) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {

        public void run(){

            // initialises gui components
            new SchemaRegistrationVisualizer();

            final Thread thisThread = new Thread( new Runnable(){

                public void run(){

                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    while( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < Math.pow( 10, 5 ) );

                    System.exit( 0 );
                }
            });

            thisThread.setPriority( Thread.MAX_PRIORITY ); thisThread.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Seems like it's shutting down your application after 100 seconds :)

Comment: it `exit`s the programme after 10**5 millisec (100 sec) - its purpose eludes me though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it creates a busy loop that makes one of the CPU cores of the machine go to 100% for 100 seconds, and then exits the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

- after invoking  new SchemaRegistrationVisualizer(), the thread waits
  for 100000 ms /100s and then exit the jvm
- The thread has been given max_priority,so the intention to stop the
  jvm after 100s seems high